# Overstayed in UK on student visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, transit-visas, lhr

I overstayed in UK on student visa for 2 years. Left UK voluntarily 2014, not being checked at airport while leaving UK, so not being marked as overstayer at that time.

I am flying to USA now with layover of 18 hours. I would like to go avail transiting without visa in London.

Question:

1. Should I be concerned about my past history in UK?
2. Should I be worried about being already flagged up in their system?
3. How about if i opt for SAR to check what they have on my file?

Please advise. Also, I would like to mention i have very strong travel history. visit a lot of countries in past 5 years (USA, Schengen multiple times)

Thanks,

Comment: *not being checked at airport while leaving UK, so not being marked as overstayer at that time* for clarity, there are no exit controls in the UK, so no one would be 'marked' on exit, but overstaying is recorded all the same.

Comment: The UK and USA do share information about visa and things like overstaying. It is not unlikely that your overstay in the UK is known in the USA and makes things difficult for you there as well. Please check before you travel (or ask relevant questions here how to find out) as you may be stopped at the border.

Comment: Apply for a visa, if successful you will no longer have this concern hanging over you.

Answer (score 7):

> Should I be concerned about my past history in UK?

Yes. Overstaying with voluntary departure would attract an [automatic 12 month entry ban](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal). However, entry may still be refused if the border officer doubts your intentions when you present yourself at the border. Having a previous overstay makes it quite likely that they will suspect you to not truly be transiting the UK. They may suspect you intend to overstay again, and can deny you entry on that basis.

> Should I be worried about being already flagged up in their system?

Certainly. All passengers who leave the UK have their details sent to the Home Office. In this way, overstayers are identified, if they have an entry to the UK without a corresponding exit. The system is not perfect, but you must assume they are aware you overstayed.

> How about if i opt for SAR to check what they have on my file?

It wouldn't hurt, but personally, I would avoid transiting the UK.